# How to find index in text of the last thing in list

Tags: python, loops

I have an assignment and I'm stuck, I would appreciate help, thanks.
this is the assignment:

```
What is the longest period of uninterrupted days that had no temperatures above 0◦C (i.e. maximum temperature below 0◦C)? What was the date of the last day of this period of time?

Write a function named get_longest_freezing() that returns both the longest number of days with uninterrupted freezing temperatures and the date of the last day of this period. The function should accept two arguments: max_dates and max_temps. Take a good look at the example of the function calls in assignment 1, and think of logical variable names.

Print the answer to both questions in one neatly formatted line. Remember to reuse any formatting functions you wrote before, and do not put your print within the function get_longest_freezing().`
```

and sample of the data file used for this:

```
EUROPEAN CLIMATE ASSESSMENT & DATASET (ECA&D), file created on 23-05-2022
THESE DATA CAN BE USED FREELY PROVIDED THAT THE FOLLOWING SOURCE IS ACKNOWLEDGED:

Klein Tank, A.M.G. and Coauthors, 2002. Daily dataset of 20th-century surface
air temperature and precipitation series for the European Climate Assessment.
Int. J. of Climatol., 22, 1441-1453.
Data and metadata available at http://www.ecad.eu

FILE FORMAT (MISSING VALUE CODE IS -9999):

01-06 SOUID: Source identifier
08-15 DATE : Date YYYYMMDD
17-21 TX   : maximum temperature in 0.1 &#176;C
23-27 Q_TX : Quality code for TX (0='valid'; 1='suspect'; 9='missing')

This is the blended series of station NETHERLANDS, DE BILT (STAID: 162).
Blended and updated with sources: 100522 906260 
See file sources.txt and stations.txt for more info.

 SOUID,    DATE,   TX, Q_TX
100522,19010101,  -24,    0
100522,19010102,  -14,    0
100522,19010103,   -6,    0
100522,19010104,  -11,    0
100522,19010105,  -20,    0
100522,19010106,  -80,    0
100522,19010107,  -68,    0
100522,19010108,   -7,    0
100522,19010109,   44,    0
100522,19010110,   61,    0
100522,19010111,   51,    0
100522,19010112,  -20,    0
100522,19010113,  -20,    0
100522,19010114,   31,    0
100522,19010115,   54,    0
100522,19010116,   42,    0
100522,19010117,   65,    0
100522,19010118,   43,    0
100522,19010119,   64,    0
100522,19010120,   72,    0
100522,19010121,  100,    0
100522,19010122,   83,    0
100522,19010123,   83,    0
100522,19010124,   57,    0
100522,19010125,   75,    0
100522,19010126,   70,    0
100522,19010127,   90,    0
100522,19010128,   54,    0
100522,19010129,   28,    0
100522,19010130,   39,    0
100522,19010131,   22,    0
100522,19010201,   23,    0
100522,19010202,   -3,    0
100522,19010203,   26,    0
100522,19010204,  -19,    0
100522,19010205,   17,    0
100522,19010206,    1,    0
100522,19010207,   27,    0`
```

This is with what I've come up so far:

````
    def read_data(text_file):
    
        # reading the file from 20th line
        data_file = open(text_file, 'r')
        data_file_read = data_file.readlines()[20:]
        
        dates = []
        temperatures = []
        
        #reading only dates and temperatures
        for line in data_file_read: 
            
            split_data = line.split(',')
            date = split_data[1]
            validation = int(split_data [3])
            
            #to fix missing value code -9999
            if validation == 0:
            
                #making it readible for computer by change it into int
                temperature_value = int(split_data[2])
            
                #temperature divided by 10 to get accurate numbers
                temperature = float(temperature_value / 10)        
            
                dates.append(date)
                temperatures.append(temperature)
            
        data_file.close()
        
        return dates, temperatures
    
    max_dates, max_temps = read_data('DeBiltTempMax2022.txt') 
    
    
    ```
    def get_longest_freezing(max_len_date, max_len_temp):
    
    count = 0
    max_count = 0
    longest_list = []
    index_list = []
    
    #count of the longest period
    for longest_temp in max_len_temp:
        
        if longest_temp < 0:
            count += 1            
            if count > max_count:
                max_count = count
                longest_list.append(longest_temp)
                
        if longest_temp >= 0:
            count = 0
            
    for index in longest_list:
            
        temp_index = max_len_temp.index(index)
        index_list.append(temp_index)
            
  
            
        last_temp = longest_list[-1]
        first = longest_list[0]
        date1 = max_len_temp.index(last_temp)
        date2 = max_len_temp.index(first)
        len_date = max_dates[date1]
#         len_date2 = max_dates[date2]
        
#     print(len_date)
    print(date1)
    print(date2)
    print(max_count)
    print(longest_list)
    print(index_list)              
    return len_date, max_count

max_len_dates, max_len_temp = get_longest_freezing(max_dates, max_temps)
````

Right now it gives me an index, however, the temperatures repeat in the text file, so it gives me the first index of the first matching temperature, is there a way to look up the index based on the whole list, so it gives me only indexes of numbers that are next to each other?

Answer (score -1):

```
input1 = str(input())

list1 = input1.split()

for i in range(len(list1)):
    list1[i] = int(list1[i])


for j in range(len(list1)):
        if list1[j] < 0:
            list1.pop(j)

print(list1)
```

Comment: Why convert the input to a string?